# hibernate save error: suppressed Exceptions Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList<E> (id=172)

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to save one entity having reference another entity getting error:

> NullPointerException Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList (id=172)

**My code:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PLTORDER")
public class Order implements java.io.Serializable {
private Company company;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", nullable = true)
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}
```

Comment: Can you add complete class def for `Order` and `Company` ?